# Extracting Text Strings in terminal

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am wondering if there is a way I can download (with `wget` probably) an html file lets say `http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html`

Here is the [html file in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eQFTp0cy). Here is the important stuff though.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  jwplayer("flvplayer").setup({ 
file: "http://77.81.98.228:8777/n2ceexa2lo4pcnokaldsf4o64qg7le7rp2xxamcxtdebx4vta3lae5iz6e/v.mp4",
skin: "beelden",
image: "http://77.81.98.228:8777/i/03/00494/wrdlm4dbigu4.jpg",
```

I need to extract `http://77.81.98.228:8777/n2ceexa2lo4pcnokaldsf4o64qg7le7rp2xxamcxtdebx4vta3lae5iz6e/v.mp4` from that html file.

so the text between `file:` and `",`

I am new to ubuntu and a terminal interface so I am unfamiliar with basic command line codes.

Answer (score 0):

First, an obligatory warning. It is usually [a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936) to try to parse HTML with simple tools like regular expressions. That said, in this case, if you are sure that what you want will always be between `file:` and the first `,`, you can use:

```
wget -O - http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html 2>/dev/null | 
    grep -oP 'file:\K[^,]*'
```

You need the `-O -` to tell `wget` to print the html to standard out instead of saving to a file. This is then piped through `grep` with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (`-P`) and `-o` to tell it to only print the matched portion of the line. The regex itself looks for `file:` and then discards it (`\K`) and then 0 or more non-`,` characters (`[^,]*`). The `2>/dev/null` discards wget's messages.

Note that in the example URL you gave, there are three matches:

```
$ wget -O - http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html | grep -oP 'file:\K[^,]*'
"http://77.81.98.228:8777/n2ceexa2lo4pcnokaldsf4o64qg7le7rp2xxamcxtdebwqbtaozwssfetq/v.mp4"
"http://vodlocker.com/dl?op=get_slides&file_code=wrdlm4dbigu4"
"http://vodlocker.com/images/vodjw_logo.png"
```

If you know you only need the first one, use `-m 1` to tell `grep` to stop after the first match:

```
$ wget -O - http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html 2>/dev/null | 
    grep -m1 -oP 'file:\K[^,]*'
"http://77.81.98.228:8777/n2ceexa2lo4pcnokaldsf4o64qg7le7rp2xxamcxtdebwqbtaozyasfetq/v.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po 'file:\s"\K[^"]+\.mp4(?=",)' file.txt
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/.*file: "([^"]+\.mp4)",/\1/p' file.txt
```

Both finds the desired string between `file "` and `",`, also we need to match `.mp4` just before `",` so that other unwanted strings do not show up in the output.

**Example:**

```
% wget -q -O- http://pastebin.com/raw/eQFTp0cy | grep -Po 'file:\s"\K[^"]+\.mp4(?=",)' 
http://77.81.98.228:8777/n2ceexa2lo4pcnokaldsf4o64qg7le7rp2xxamcxtdebx4vta3lae5iz6e/v.mp4


% wget -q -O- http://pastebin.com/raw/eQFTp0cy | sed -nr 's/.*file: "([^"]+\.mp4)",/\1/p'
http://77.81.98.228:8777/n2ceexa2lo4pcnokaldsf4o64qg7le7rp2xxamcxtdebx4vta3lae5iz6e/v.mp4
```